# Does the phrase "shotgun wedding" have a negative connotation?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage, phrase-requests

For instance, if someone says

> They have a shotgun wedding.

does it carry a mocking tone?

Is there another phrase or word to politely describe someone has to get married because of unplanned pregnancy?

Comment: Obviously it's invariably a facetious / mocking usage, given the *specific* allusion is to an irate father forcing his daughter's lover into marriage ***at gunpoint***. That's just not how things work in modern Western society.

Comment: I suppose that "give the [not-yet-born] baby a name" would imply a less coerced decision to wed before the future bride gives birth. The opposite situation arises in the lyrics to the Supremes song "Love Child," in which the narrator says that she "had no name." There are also degrees of negativity in allusions to a couple's having been sexually intimate before marriage: "make an honest woman of her" is particularly retrograde; "make it legal" is somewhat less offensive (because it doesn't single out the woman for opprobrium). None of these phrases would qualify as enlightened, however.

Comment: The phrase is often used metaphorically for an awkward (or merely surprising) combination of two devices or organizations or concepts.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Now that you explained it. I have always assumed *shotgun* refers to the situation that caught one off guard and the swiftness of marriage. lol.

Comment: @Jalene Despite what the dictionary says, I've always assumed *quick* to be the meaning too. It may be because it's always used in the context of *quickly, without planning* (e.g. Vegas weddings officiated by people dressed up as Elvis). The meaning of *forced* (instead of just *quick*) is almost never clearly conveyed in contexts I'm aware of. There could easily be some overlap (you have to get married quickly because you've been forced into it), but I would still point to the *quick* meaning if forced to choose between the two.

Comment: Negative *connotation*? No, a negative **denotation**.